# Erro ao comparar datas PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="dataInicio" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Data" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" />
<input name="dataFim" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Data" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" />
```

**MySQL**

```
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
```

**PHP**

```
$dataInicio = (isset($_POST['dataInicio'])) ? '2017-09-25' : date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataInicio']));
$dataFim = (isset($_POST['dataFim'])) ? date("Y-m-d") : date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataFim']));
```

E por fim o teste que estou fazendo para retornar o intervalo de dias que preciso:
**PHP**

```
SELECT date,time,resultCode,hostname,user,sites,qt_acessos,bytes
                FROM tblResumo
                WHERE 
                    date >= '$dataInicio' AND 
                    date <= '$dataFim'
```

Porém tenho o retorno de TODOS os registros, independente da data informada no formulário da minha aplicação! E o que não entendo é que conferindo no POST, os valores informados para o intervalo de datas está lá corretamente. Estou imprimindo os valores como JSON, caso esta informação seja útil.
Onde estou errando?
Antecipo o meu agradecimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um problema na sua definição das variáveis `$dataInicio` e `$dataFim`. O operador ternário retorna '2017-09-25' e `date("Y-m-d")` caso **exista** dados no item `$_POST` correspondente.

Imagino que o que você queira é preencher com  '2017-09-25' ou `date("Y-m-d")` (hoje) caso **não exista** dados no array `$_POST`. Portanto, usando `!isset()`:

```
$dataInicio = (!isset($_POST['dataInicio'])) ? '2017-09-25' : date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataInicio']));
$dataFim = (!isset($_POST['dataFim'])) ? date("Y-m-d") : date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataFim']));
```

Comment: Nossa, cara! Que vacilo, esqueci da negação :(
Muito obrigado! Resolveu o meu problema aqui. Sempre tive dúvidas com operador ternário e isso só agravou quando fiz um teste contrário `$dataInicio = (isset($_POST['dataInicio'])) ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataInicio'])) : '2017-09-25'; ` e não estava retornando nada. Aí fui verificar agora e na verdade não existiam registros. Enfim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Existe um campo do tipo `date` em html:

```
<input type="date">
```

Isso padronizará as informações passadas no campo, ao invez de serem válidadas depois se são todos números por exemplo.

No `SELECT`você pode utilizar o comando SQL `BETWEEN`:

Esse comando pega valores entre paramêtros passados, como datas. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31';
```

**Obs:** Existe em [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) uma função chamada datepicker onde você consegue otimizar todo o campo da data.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, cara! Vou mudar para `date`. Quanto ao `datepicker`, já o utilizo! Tive um problema utilizando o `BETWEEN` no SQL, por serem várias condições no meu `WHERE`, mas mesmo assim eu te agradeço pelas dicas e pela atenção! Abraço.